# Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'ToolbarItem<Void, Text>' conform to 'View'

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm supporting iOS 13 and up. I wish to use the new `.toolbar` modifier for an optional feature, in devices using iOS 14 and up. I'm using Xcode 13.0 RC 1, build 13A233, but the issue also occurs in Xcode 12.5.1. I have created the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyToolbar<T>: ViewModifier where T: View {
    let toolbarContent: () -> T
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            content
                .toolbar(content: self.toolbarContent)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func myToolbar<T: View>(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> T) -> some View {
        self.modifier(MyToolbar(toolbarContent: content))
    }
}

struct MyToolbar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello, world")
                .myToolbar {
                    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                        Text("Hello, world!")
//                        ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
//                            Text("Hello, world!")
//                        }
                    } else {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I have included the preview bit, so the above can be pasted into an empty file in any Xcode SwiftUI project. It works. When I uncomment the `ToolbarItem` statement, I get the following errors:

```
Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'ToolbarItem<Void, Text>' conform to 'View'
Static method 'buildLimitedAvailability' requires that 'ToolbarItem<Void, Text>' conform to 'View'
```

How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue is that the `.toolbar` modifier's block is defined to return something conforming to the `ToolbarContent` protocol. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/toolbar(content:)-5w0tj):

```swift
func toolbar<Content>(content: () -> Content) -> some View where Content : ToolbarContent
```

As such, within your view modifier

```swift
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        content
            .toolbar(content: self.toolbarContent)
    }
}
```

… you need to ensure that `self.toolbarContent` matches that `() -> ToolbarContent` type signature.

Just from glancing at your code, I'd be inclined to first try changing your conformance of `T` from `T: View` to `T: ToolbarContent`. By eye that looks like it might be enough, but it's possible you might need to do a bit more work to tidy everything up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@ToolbarContentBuilder`

```swift
extension View {

    @ToolbarContentBuilder
    func toolbarContent() -> some ToolbarContent {
        ...
    }
```

You can add your extension like this

```swift
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            content
                .toolbar(content: self.toolbarContent)
        }
}
```